# Java "Else without if" error. What did I do wrong?

Tags: java

```
public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter your guess");
            System.out.println("\n");
            int Guess = userInputScanner.nextInt();

            if(Guess == randomNumber)

                System.out.print("Good");

                System.out.print("\n");

            else if(Guess < randomNumber)

                System.out.print("Higher");

                System.out.println("\n");

            else if(Guess > randomNumber)

                System.out.print("Lower");

                System.out.println("\n");
        }
        while(Guess != randomNumber);

    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the curly braces for your if and else statements.

Comment: You also don't need the last `else if` since there can be no other possible outcome for your code block. A number is either equal, greater, or less than another number, so you can simply omit the conditional and use `else`

Comment: Unlike Python we need to add braces other wise even though u indent the code its not going display appropriate results.

Answer (score 2):

add brackets `{}` around if and if else body, Java doesn't work like python in if else and indentation

```
if(Guess == randomNumber) { 
    System.out.print("Good");

    System.out.print("\n");

} else if(Guess < randomNumber) {

    System.out.print("Higher");

    System.out.println("\n");

} else if(Guess > randomNumber) {

    System.out.print("Lower");

    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Comment: Think you might need to add an example ;)

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
if(Guess == randomNumber){
    System.out.print("Good");

    System.out.print("\n");

}else if(Guess < randomNumber){

    System.out.print("Higher");

    System.out.println("\n");

}else if(Guess > randomNumber){

    System.out.print("Lower");

    System.out.println("\n");}
```

With the braces around if-else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to put multiple statements inside an `if` block without curly braces. In other languages, the indentation controls the structure, but Java is free-form, so without braces, only one statement is grouped to each `if`/`else`.

So the program groups the first statement to the `if`, then the next statement is alone, then you have an `else` without an immediately preceding `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You  need to add `{}` after every if condition and Guess variable need to declare before do while
here the complete code , already compile it and  nothing wrong

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame{



public static void main(String[] args){


double randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int Guess = 0;

do{

    System.out.println("Enter your guess");
    System.out.println("\n");

    Guess = userInputScanner.nextInt();

    if(Guess == randomNumber) {
        System.out.print("Good");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    else if(Guess < randomNumber) {
        System.out.print("Higher");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    else if(Guess > randomNumber) {
        System.out.print("Lower");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
while(Guess != randomNumber);



}
}
```